# Rails second-order association filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've got a few models, as follows:

```
class Examinee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, as: :invoker
  has_many :tests

  def get_location
    t = self.tests.last
    l = nil
    if t.blank?
      a = self.activities.last
      l = a.location unless a.blank?
    else
      l = t.location
    end
    l
  end
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :examinee
  has_many :activities, as: :invoker
  delegate :location, to: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :tests
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :users
  has_many :tests, through: :users
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoker, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Now, the logic of associating an `examinee` with its proper `location` is defined in the `get_location` method.

As I need to list examinees alongside their associated `location`, what I currently do in the `examinees` index is this:

```
def index
  @examinees = Examinee.preload(:activities, :tests).references(:locations).order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

A new client request has risen: to filter this list by location. Naturally, I've tried all variations of `where`:

```
@examinees.where(location_id: 2)
@examinees.where(location: {id: 2})
Examinee.preload(activities: :location, tests: :location).where(location_id: 2)
```

and a few more variations of these. Nothing works. Has anybody here experienced with this kind of second-order association filtering?

**EDIT:**
I can get the following queries to work:

```
Examinee.joins(:activities, tests: :user).where(users: {location_id: 2})
Examinee.joins(:activities, tests: :user).where(activities: {location_id: 2})
```

but I need their disjunction (OR result), which isn't available for Rails 4.

Comment: See https://ducktypelabs.com/four-ways-to-filter-has_many-associations/

Comment: @maxpleaner I've read this prior to posting here. It relates to first-order associations

Comment: `where("locations.id = ?", some_id)` does that not work?

Comment: nope, I still get the same error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'locations.id' in 'where clause': SELECT "examinees".* FROM "examinees" WHERE "locations"."id" = 2` (I've put qutoemarks instead of backticks to preserve code formatting)

Comment: what about `where("users.location_id = ?", some_id)`? Then you could do `where("users.location_id = ? OR activities.location_id = ?", some_id, another_id)`